# Error in deploying call_runtime contract from ink!

Tags: ink, smart-contract, runtime

I am running [`call_runtime`](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/integration-tests/call-runtime) from ink. It builds successfully, but when trying to upload contract, It gives `system.ExtrinsicFailed contracts.CodeRejected` error. Someone please advice what I am doing wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error above is most likely because `contracts` pallet on Aleph Zero is not configured to support `call_runtime`.

Aleph Zero configuration

```
impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    type Time = Timestamp;
    type Randomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    // The safest default is to allow no calls at all. This is unsafe experimental feature with no support in ink!
    type CallFilter = Nothing;
    type WeightPrice = pallet_transaction_payment::Pallet<Self>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_contracts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
    type ChainExtension = ();
    type Schedule = Schedule;
    type CallStack = [pallet_contracts::Frame<Self>; 16];
    type DepositPerByte = DepositPerByte;
    type DefaultDepositLimit = ConstU128<{ u128::MAX }>;
    type DepositPerItem = DepositPerItem;
    type AddressGenerator = pallet_contracts::DefaultAddressGenerator;
    type MaxCodeLen = ConstU32<{ 128 * 1024 }>;
    type MaxStorageKeyLen = ConstU32<128>;
    type UnsafeUnstableInterface = ConstBool<false>;
    type MaxDebugBufferLen = ConstU32<{ 2 * 1024 * 1024 }>;
}
```

To be able to use `call_runtime`, `CallFilter` and `UnsafeUnstableInterface` should be configured as below:

```
// In your node's runtime configuration file (runtime.rs)
impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
  …
  // `Everything` or anything that will allow for the `Balances::transfer` extrinsic.
  type CallFilter = frame_support::traits::Everything; 
  type UnsafeUnstableInterface = ConstBool<true>;
  …
}
```